# ExternalInterface.addCallback doesnot runs well

Tags: javascript, facebook, flash, token

I try make a login facebook mechanism in my flash apps.
But when I try to get the token access form callback page, the ExternalInterface.addCallback that will get and send to flash didn;t runs well. 
How I can solve it?

This my code:

```
var accessToken:String ="";
tombol.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
    attemptToAuthenticate();
    tombol.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
}

function attemptToAuthenticate(...permissions):void{
  var scope:String = "";
  if (permissions.length > 0){
   scope = "&scope=" + permissions.join(",");
  }
  ExternalInterface.call("window.open","https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=245127485627150&type=user_agent&redirect_uri=http://localhost/satu/callback.html"+scope,"facebookLoginWindow","height=370, width=600");    

teks.text = "success get token from server fb";

ExternalInterface.addCallback("setAccessToken", setAccessToken);    

ExternalInterface.call("function() {"
       + "window.setAccessToken = function(hashValue){"
       + "var satu1 = document.getElementById('satu');"
       + "satu1.setAccessToken(hashValue);"
       + "}"
       + "}");

ExternalInterface.call("window.alert", "hashValue");
teks.text += " get from flash"; 
 }

 function setAccessToken(a_hashValue:String):void{
  teks.text += "setaccesstoken";
  var hashParams:Array = a_hashValue.substr(1).split("&");
      var hashKeyAndValue:Array;
      for (var i:int = 0; i < hashParams.length; i++){
      hashKeyAndValue = (hashParams[i] as String).split("=");
  if (hashKeyAndValue[0] == "access_token"){
      this.accessToken = hashKeyAndValue[1];
      break;
    }
  }
  this.request("me","");
  }

 // some code below.....
```

Comment: Is there some error throwed by flash?

Comment: in your html, did you have set the *allowscriptaccess=always* and, in flash, *System.security.allowDomain("*");* ?

Comment: Based on my code, when I run it, it's stopped at ExternalInterface.call("window.alert", "hashValue"); teks.text += " get from flash";} >>> because I put set text in text in teks to see the flow. And I conclude the setAccessToken doesn't called back because teks.text += "setaccesstoken"; doesn't appear.
should I set allowscriptaceess=always in my page?
and where I can put "system.security.allowDomain("");" down in my apps?

Comment: @DeividiCavarzan: I can still solve it, how the configure system.security.allowdomain? FYI-Both of them in same domain.

Comment: hum... ok. it appears that you declare te `window.setAcessToken()` but never call that... try call `window.setAccessToken()`; after declare that to see ehat happens.

Comment: I'm sorry my last comment is "I can't solve it...." not "I can ...".
Ok, I wanna go check that part.

Comment: How if I send my source code?

Comment: I have the following actionsscript that works... see: https://gist.github.com/cavarzan/ca112df048e53bcc0455

Comment: I don't get it, what is bindable, and how to use that gist?

Comment: gist it's just a copy / paste for code source. [Bindable] is for bind the variable to notify every point that use this variable.